# List customers who sold most in mssql

Tags: sql-server, join, multi-select

I'm new to sql.
I have to select top 3 companies who have the highest sells

Company Table:
CompanyId, Compnayname,etc

Orders Table:
OrderId, companyId,price,etc

select top 3 companyname , (select sum(price) from ordes) as Maximum from company order by Maximum Desc?

I think i need to join these but i cant find a way around it

Answer (score 5):

Join these tables, group by company's name and order by their total sales:

```
select top 3 c.Companyname, sum(o.price) as TotalSales
from Orders o
inner join Company c on c.CompanyId = o.companyid
group by c.Companyname
order by TotalSales desc
```